# Cron job is showing failure in my custom module. magennto EE 1.14.1.0

Tags: php, xml, magento

I have a custom module and that custom module will dynamically add 2 entries in cron_schedule table for running the cron on that particular time.

The cron is running and it shows the failure message.

In the cron _schedule table the job code is (vtrio_bannerexpire) is calling method in Model\Observer.php file. The functionality of that method is clear the cache of layout. But cache is not flushing (thats may be cron_schedule shows the error message).
[image: Error message from cron_sheduler table]

The cron_schedule table 'message' column is updating the following error.

```
    ---EXCEPTION---
 exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid model/method     definition, expecting "model/class::method", got "" instead.' in /var/www/vhosts/stage/current/shop/app/Mage.php:595
 Stack trace:
 #0 /var/www/vhosts/stage/current/shop/app/code/community/Aoe/Scheduler  /Helper/Data.php(295): Mage::throwException('Invalid model/m...')
 #1 /var/www/vhosts/stage/current/shop/app/code/community/Aoe/Scheduler/Model/Job.php(143): Aoe_Scheduler_Helper_Data->getCallBack('')
 #2 /var/www/vhosts/stage/current/shop/app/code/community/Aoe/Scheduler/Model/Schedule.php(192): Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Job->getCallback()
 #3 /var/www/vhosts/stage/current/shop/app/code/community/Aoe/Scheduler/Model/Schedule.php(582): Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Schedule->runNow(true)
 #4 /var/www/vhosts/stage/current/shop/app/code/community/Aoe/Scheduler/Model/Observer.php(39): Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Schedule->process()
 #5 /var/www/vhosts/stage/current/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model /App.php(1341):  Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Observer->dispatch(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
 #6 /var/www/vhosts/stage/current/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1320):  Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Aoe_Scheduler_Model_Observer), 'dispatch', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
 #7 /var/www/vhosts/stage/current/shop/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('default', Array)
 #8 /var/www/vhosts/stage/current/shop/cron.php(77): Mage::dispatchEvent('default')
 #9 {main}
```

Model (Model\Observer.php)

```
<?php
class Vtrio_BannerExpire_Model_Observer
{
    public function crontest()
    {
       Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->cleanType('layout');
    }
 }
```

Config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
   <modules>
      <Vtrio_BannerExpire>
        <version>1.0</version>    
    </Vtrio_BannerExpire>
   </modules> 
   <global>
      <models>
         <vtrio_bannerexpire>
             <class>Vtrio_BannerExpire_Model</class>
         </vtrio_bannerexpire>
         <enterprise_banner_resource>
                <class>Vtrio_BannerExpire_Model_Resource</class>
         </enterprise_banner_resource>
      </models>

      <resources>
         <bannerexpire_setup>
            <setup>
               <module>Vtrio_BannerExpire</module>
            </setup>
            <connection>
               <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
         </bannerexpire_setup>
         <bannerexpire_write>
            <connection>
               <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
         </bannerexpire_write>
         <bannerexpire_read>
            <connection>
               <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
         </bannerexpire_read>
      </resources>      
   </global>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <vtrio_bannerexpires>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Vtrio_BannerExpire</module>
                    <frontName>croncalling</frontName>
                </args>
            </vtrio_bannerexpires>
        </routers>  
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Comment: Where are you defining the cron job's model alias? Config XML or database?

Comment: I should re-phrase - I can't see where you're defining the cron job - the error message indicates that you haven't. It doesn't appear to be done in config.xml so I assume you've done it via the AOE Scheduler's interface - can you post a screenshot of the job configuration?